# OSx Mavericks (10.9.1.) randomly restarts

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, kernel-panic, reboot

After having updated my macbook pro (mid 2010) and having it run without problems for some month, it now started to randomly reboot when I'm working on something.

Resetting the VRAM didn't help.
Any ideas?

Latest panic log:

```
Sun Jan 26 08:59:07 2014
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f8e5acfac): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00070000: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff80abc40000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.4.12/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff808824a560 : 0xffffff800c222f69 
0xffffff808824a5e0 : 0xffffff7f8e5acfac 
...
  Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.4.12)[A4934A66-0E30-36E9-984A-650481102449]@0xffffff7f8e59f000->0xffffff7f8e5b1fff
        dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.4.12)[661E3C87-5B97-3272-88FF-B9BA9B6E24ED]@0xffffff7f8e597000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[045D5D6F-AD1E-36DB-A249-A346E2B48E54]@0xffffff7f8cb24000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f8c8ba000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.6)[38E388A5-92D6-3388-B799-F2498E582287]@0xffffff7f8cc16000
        dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[E04639C5-D734-3AB3-A682-FE66694C6653]@0xffffff7f8e59a000
     com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.1.8)[0A1B6F41-168D-307A-BABD-162F3B3C2786]@0xffffff7f8cc69000->0xffffff7f8ced8fff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f8c8ba000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.6)[86BA68C6-18DD-30A1-ABF6-54597AD6C277]@0xffffff7f8cc59000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.6)[38E388A5-92D6-3388-B799-F2498E582287]@0xffffff7f8cc16000
     com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(8.1.8)[3666E0FC-87C7-3329-BD8C-2F1ADED100A4]@0xffffff7f8cee3000->0xffffff7f8d18ffff
        dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.1.8)[0A1B6F41-168D-307A-BABD-162F3B3C2786]@0xffffff7f8cc69000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f8c8ba000
     com.apple.GeForceTesla(8.1.8)[7DAF283F-6FD3-3783-B3CC-D23964F1B9B8]@0xffffff7f8dba7000->0xffffff7f8dc71fff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f8c8ba000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.6)[86BA68C6-18DD-30A1-ABF6-54597AD6C277]@0xffffff7f8cc59000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.6)[38E388A5-92D6-3388-B799-F2498E582287]@0xffffff7f8cc16000
        dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.1.8)[0A1B6F41-168D-307A-BABD-162F3B3C2786]@0xffffff7f8cc69000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
13B42

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D9369E3-D0A5-31B6-8D16-BFFBBB390393
Kernel slide:     0x000000000c000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800c200000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 24662213098073
last loaded kext at 1541007827836: com.apple.filesystems.afpfs  11.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8e6cd000, size 348160)
last unloaded kext at 446302835610: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.9 (addr 0xffffff7f8d1b5000, size 57344)
loaded kexts:
com.manycamllc.driver.ManyCamDriver 0.0.9
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.0
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.11
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.1.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.0f6
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 8.1.8
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.9b9
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.9.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.12
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.4fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.6d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.5.1d27
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  650.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   600.34
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b4
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.10
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  21
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

System Profile:
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533642465238432D47372020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533642465238432D47372020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545032B9SA02, 320,07 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: Use Terminal to run the command shown at http://pastebin.com/PjBZgSba then restart the Mac. You'll get verbose boot, verbose shut down and more importantly: the next .panic file will show more information in the backtrace.

Answer (score 1):

The panic log show that it's a GPU panic. The system profile indicates that it's a MacBookPro6,2.

Based on this, there are a few possible courses of action:

- Disable graphics switching in System Preferences → Energy Saver.
- Take it to an Apple Store. It's unfortunately no longer covered by [MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010): Intermittent black screen or loss of video](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4088) so you'll probably have to pay for any repairs.

Comment: disabling the graphic switching improved the situation a lot. Spontaneous reboots are down to maybe once per day, but I still get the same panic logs: 
`com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.4.12)...
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla....
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(8.1.8)...
com.apple.GeForceTesla(8.1.8).....`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model and the same symptoms, and it [might be a known issue](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4088?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). The Internet says that some people were able to get a replacement, even outside the warranty. I'll try that for myself.